slow boot time on fresh manjaro install
so whenever I boot into my manjaro system, I am getting this error efter the grub menu
[    0.003650] call_irq_handler: 1.55 No irq handler for vector
[    0.003650] call_irq_handler: 2.55 No irq handler for vector
[    0.003650] call_irq_handler: 3.55 No irq handler for vector
[    0.003650] call_irq_handler: 4.55 No irq handler for vector
[    0.003650] call_irq_handler: 5.55 No irq handler for vector
[    0.003650] call_irq_handler: 6.55 No irq handler for vector
[    0.003650] call_irq_handler: 7.55 No irq handler for vector
[    0.003650] call_irq_handler: 8.55 No irq handler for vector
[    0.003650] call_irq_handler: 9.55 No irq handler for vector
[    0.003650] call_irq_handler: 10.55 No irq handler for vector

And those errors are there for a while (a couple of seconds) before the system fully boots.
I couldn't find much info about this particular error other than others having similar messages but not able to complete booting at all.
I might be wrong, but to me those messages looks like errors that could be solved for a faster boot.
Searching a bit for it in dmesg I found the surrounding messages:
[    0.162214] LSM support for eBPF active
[    0.162232] AppArmor: AppArmor initialized
[    0.162279] Mount-cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 6, 262144 bytes, linear)
[    0.162300] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 6, 262144 bytes, linear)
[    0.274937] smpboot: CPU0: AMD Ryzen 5 1600X Six-Core Processor (family: 0x17, model: 0x1, stepping:
0x1)
[    0.275188] Performance Events: Fam17h+ core perfctr, AMD PMU driver.
[    0.275195] ... version:                0
[    0.275196] ... bit width:              48
[    0.275197] ... generic registers:      6
[    0.275198] ... value mask:             0000ffffffffffff
[    0.275200] ... max period:             00007fffffffffff
[    0.275201] ... fixed-purpose events:   0
[    0.275202] ... event mask:             000000000000003f
[    0.275308] signal: max sigframe size: 1776
[    0.275341] rcu: Hierarchical SRCU implementation.
[    0.275342] rcu:     Max phase no-delay instances is 1000.
[    0.275767] MCE: In-kernel MCE decoding enabled.
[    0.275815] NMI watchdog: Enabled. Permanently consumes one hw-PMU counter.
[    0.275931] smp: Bringing up secondary CPUs ...
[    0.276041] smpboot: x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[    0.276042] .... node  #0, CPUs:        #1  #2  #3  #4  #5
[    0.003650] call_irq_handler: 1.55 No irq handler for vector
[    0.003650] call_irq_handler: 2.55 No irq handler for vector
[    0.003650] call_irq_handler: 3.55 No irq handler for vector
[    0.003650] call_irq_handler: 4.55 No irq handler for vector
[    0.003650] call_irq_handler: 5.55 No irq handler for vector
[    0.287482]   #6  #7  #8  #9 #10 #11
[    0.003650] call_irq_handler: 6.55 No irq handler for vector
[    0.003650] call_irq_handler: 7.55 No irq handler for vector
[    0.003650] call_irq_handler: 8.55 No irq handler for vector
[    0.003650] call_irq_handler: 9.55 No irq handler for vector
[    0.003650] call_irq_handler: 10.55 No irq handler for vector
[    0.300815] smp: Brought up 1 node, 12 CPUs
[    0.300815] smpboot: Total of 12 processors activated (86267.32 BogoMIPS)
[    0.302586] devtmpfs: initialized

not sure if that means anything to anyone
$ sudo lshw -short
H/W path                Device          Class          Description
==================================================================
                                        system         System Product Name (SKU)
/0                                      bus            ROG STRIX B550-I GAMING
/0/0                                    memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/27                                   memory         16GiB System Memory
/0/27/0                                 memory         8GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregister
/0/27/1                                 memory         8GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregister
/0/29                                   memory         576KiB L1 cache
/0/2a                                   memory         3MiB L2 cache
/0/2b                                   memory         16MiB L3 cache
/0/2c                                   processor      AMD Ryzen 5 1600X Six-Core Processor
/0/100                                  bridge         Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Root Complex
/0/100/0.2                              generic        Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) I/O Memory Management
/0/100/1.1                              bridge         Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge
/0/100/1.1/0            /dev/nvme0      storage        WD_BLACK SN850X HS 2000GB
/0/100/1.1/0/0          hwmon0          disk           NVMe disk
/0/100/1.1/0/2          /dev/ng0n1      disk           NVMe disk
/0/100/1.1/0/1          /dev/nvme0n1    disk           2TB NVMe disk
/0/100/1.1/0/1/1        /dev/nvme0n1p1  volume         15GiB Linux swap volume
/0/100/1.1/0/1/2                        volume         399MiB Windows FAT volume
/0/100/1.1/0/1/3        /dev/nvme0n1p3  volume         725GiB EXT4 volume
/0/100/1.1/0/1/4        /dev/nvme0n1p4  volume         1121GiB EXT4 volume
/0/100/1.2                              bridge         Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge
/0/100/1.2/0                            bus            500 Series Chipset USB 3.1 XHCI Controller
/0/100/1.2/0/0          usb1            bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1.2/0/0/1                        bus            4-Port USB 2.1 Hub
/0/100/1.2/0/0/1/2                      bus            4-Port USB 2.1 Hub
/0/100/1.2/0/0/1/2/4                    input          USB Receiver
/0/100/1.2/0/0/1/2/4/0  input30         input          Logitech Craft
/0/100/1.2/0/0/1/2/4/1  input31         input          Logitech MX Master 2S
/0/100/1.2/0/0/5                        communication  AX200 Bluetooth
/0/100/1.2/0/0/6                        input          AURA LED Controller
/0/100/1.2/0/1          usb2            bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1.2/0/1/1                        bus            4-Port USB 3.1 Hub
/0/100/1.2/0/1/1/1                      generic        USB 10/100/1000 LAN
/0/100/1.2/0/1/1/2                      bus            4-Port USB 3.1 Hub
/0/100/1.2/0/1/1/3      card4           multimedia     Belkin USB-C Dock
/0/100/1.2/0.1                          storage        500 Series Chipset SATA Controller
/0/100/1.2/0.2                          bridge         500 Series Chipset Switch Upstream Port
/0/100/1.2/0.2/0                        bridge         Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/100/1.2/0.2/4                        bridge         Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/100/1.2/0.2/8                        bridge         Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/100/1.2/0.2/8/0      wlp6s0          network        Wi-Fi 6 AX200
/0/100/1.2/0.2/9                        bridge         Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/100/1.2/0.2/9/0      enp7s0          network        Ethernet Controller I225-V
/0/100/3.1                              bridge         Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge
/0/100/3.1/0            /dev/fb0        display        GM204 [GeForce GTX 970]
/0/100/3.1/0.1          card0           multimedia     GM204 High Definition Audio Controller
/0/100/3.1/0.1/0        input5          input          HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3
/0/100/3.1/0.1/1        input6          input          HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7
/0/100/3.1/0.1/2        input7          input          HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8
/0/100/3.1/0.1/3        input8          input          HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9
/0/100/7.1                              bridge         Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Internal PCIe GPP Bri
/0/100/7.1/0                            generic        Zeppelin/Raven/Raven2 PCIe Dummy Function
/0/100/7.1/0.2                          generic        Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Platform Security Pro
/0/100/7.1/0.3                          bus            Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) USB 3.0 Host Controll
/0/100/7.1/0.3/0        usb3            bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/7.1/0.3/0/1      card2           multimedia     Blue Snowball
/0/100/7.1/0.3/0/4      card3           multimedia     HD Webcam C525
/0/100/7.1/0.3/1        usb4            bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/8.1                              bridge         Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Internal PCIe GPP Bri
/0/100/8.1/0                            generic        Zeppelin/Renoir PCIe Dummy Function
/0/100/8.1/0.2                          storage        FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
/0/100/8.1/0.3          card1           multimedia     Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller
/0/100/8.1/0.3/0        input10         input          HD-Audio Generic Rear Mic
/0/100/8.1/0.3/1        input11         input          HD-Audio Generic Rear Mic
/0/100/8.1/0.3/2        input12         input          HD-Audio Generic Line
/0/100/8.1/0.3/3        input13         input          HD-Audio Generic Line Out
/0/100/8.1/0.3/4        input14         input          HD-Audio Generic Front Headphone
/0/100/8.1/0.3/5        input9          input          HD-Audio Generic Front Mic
/0/100/14                               bus            FCH SMBus Controller
/0/100/14.3                             bridge         FCH LPC Bridge
/0/100/14.3/0                           system         System Board
/0/100/14.3/1                           system         AT Real-Time Clock
/0/100/14.3/2                           system         Motherboard registers
/0/100/14.3/3                           system         Motherboard registers
/0/101                                  bridge         Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridg
/0/102                                  bridge         Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridg
/0/103                                  bridge         Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridg
/0/104                                  bridge         Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridg
/0/105                                  bridge         Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridg
/0/106                                  bridge         Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridg
/0/107                                  bridge         Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 1
/0/108                                  bridge         Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 1
/0/109                                  bridge         Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 1
/0/10a                                  bridge         Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 1
/0/10b                                  bridge         Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 1
/0/10c                                  bridge         Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 1
/0/10d                                  bridge         Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 1
/0/10e                                  bridge         Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 1
/1                      input0          input          Power Button
/2                      input1          input          Power Button
/3                      input2          input          PC Speaker
/4                      input4          input          Eee PC WMI hotkeys
/5                      enp2s0f0u1u1    network        USB 10/100/1000 LAN


Please [edit] your Question and add sudo lshw -short.

I would try this: 1) update your UEFI BIOS; 2) Check your IRQ assignments in the BIOS (did you change those?); 3) Is your system unstable? (crashes, stops for a while, etc.)

for me to fully understand, you are saying update the firmware on the motherboard right? I honestly do not know what IRQ assignments are, so if I did change them it was unintentional. The system is really stable, and there are to me no noticeable issues in terms of performance.

looks like upgrading the bios on the motherboard did the trick
